# Como criar menu drop down

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, menu

Estou criando um simples menu dropdown com typescript. Entretanto esta acontecendo um comportamento estranho. Quando eu clico em um item do menu que não possui elementos para serem exibidos, ele esta mostrando o itens do submenu. Como posso fazer para exibir o sub menu apenas quando eu clicar no item que possui submenu?  Até agora meu código esta assim:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  clickedUser: number = 0;
  public categories: Categories[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      isDropDownMenu: false,
      description: "description1",
      enabled: false,
      dropDownTarget: "",
      subMenuList: []
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isDropDownMenu: false,
      description: "description2",
      dropDownTarget: "",
      enabled: false,
      subMenuList: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      isDropDownMenu: true,
      description: "description3",
      dropDownTarget: "description3Target",
      enabled: false,
      subMenuList: ["subDescription1", "subDescription2", "subDescription3"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**menu-item.component.ts**

```
export class MenuItemComponent implements OnInit {
  clickedUser: number = 0;
  @Input() categories: Categories[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  activeMenu() {
    this.clickedUser++;
    this.categories.forEach(item => {
      if(item.isDropDownMenu) {
        if(this.clickedUser > 0) {
          item.enabled = true;
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**menu-item.component.html**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li *ngFor="let item of categories; let i = index" (click)="activeMenu()">
    {{ item.description }}

    <ul class="sub-menu"  *ngIf="item.isDropDownMenu && item.enabled">
      <li *ngFor="let subMenu of item.subMenuList">
        {{ subMenu }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Print do problema**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou um "pouquinho" de lógica aí no seu código. A propriedade **clicked** para contabilizar cliques não é necessária *(não no contexto desta pergunta)*, o ideal é utilizar uma propriedade **`boolean`** para controlar a visualização do sub-menu, assim também como faltou o conhecimento do próprio framework. Não precisa percorrer o array na função `activeMenu()`, basta passar a referência do item que foi clicado pela função e usar essa referencia para controlar a view.

###### Arquivo TS

```
 control = false;

 activeMenu(item: Categories) {
  if (item.isDropDownMenu) {
    this.control = !this.control;  // Se true vira false e vice-versa
    item.enabled = this.control;   // controla a view dos sub-menus
  }
}
```

###### Arquivo HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li *ngFor="let item of categories; let i = index" (click)="activeMenu(item)">
    {{ item.description }}

    <ul class="sub-menu"  *ngIf="item.isDropDownMenu && item.enabled">
      <li *ngFor="let subMenu of item.subMenuList">
        {{ subMenu }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Pode ver um exemplo funcional [aqui](https://ng-run.com/edit/fY6DUUbrOVmipWRnlpX0)

Comment: Boa man... simples e direto!! realmente não havia a necessidade de iterar sobre o array de categorias. vlw!!